# Sending input to a pop-up window

Tags: winapi, input, popup

I need a way to enter a password to the pop-up window below:

[image: The pop-up to which I want to send input.]

I suppose Python has a way, although I couldn't find it, and I suspect WinAPI might be useful here as well.

How can I do so through code?

Comment: `nircmd win child dlgsettext` command could do that: "dlgsettext: Set the text to the specified control inside a dialog-box.". The problem is finding the dialog ID to tell `nircmdc` which dialog to send the text to.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The windows cmd doesn't know this comment, are you sure this would work? I'm using windows 7

Comment: you have to download it first. it's free.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I managed to get nircmd to work in general, but can you explain shortly how is this command used?
I'm very short in time and documentation about these things isn't very detailed...

Answer (score 1):

Use the Win32 API [`SendInput()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) function to simulate keyboard activity.  Use a hook from [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) or [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx) to detect when the dialog is created and shown, and then send the desired keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

use nircmd to achieve your goal.
download nircmd and copy exe files to Windows directory.
use cmd command to execute the following
nircmd.exe win dlgsettext class "#32770" 1152 "heihei"

#32770 is the window class, use Window Spy tool to get this info.
1152 is the control id, use Winexplorer tool to get this. (In Winexplorer, it's called itemid) in your case, this should be the input box for password.
heihei is the text you want to input.